# How do you type an upside-down underscore in vim?

Tags: vim

I am wondering is it possible to display an upside-down underscore in vim. I am using windows and even when I try alt-0175, it still does not display it. I have gvim.

Comment: `alt-0175` isn't of much use unless you know what font you're using. e.g. 0175 in times new roman is "latin small letter w with circumflex". not an underscore

Comment: Check [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Entering_special_characters) out.

Comment: My apologies; my answer was for LaTeX (which I write in Vim), not for Vim itself.  That's why I shouldn't answer questions after 1am.

Answer (score 4):

I found it, use the digraph `'m`.  [Digraph page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Entering_special_characters).